# Json Decode - PHP

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

I'm trying decode a json from an one API, but when i try the code:

```
 <?php
   $json = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=270EBE5B0B2501EE0FC750196325406B&steamids=76561198260508210");
   $decode = json_decode($json,1);
   echo $decode['realname'];
  ?>
```

This appears:

```
Notice: Undefined index: realname in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\CSGrow\index.php on line 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inspect the API response closely, then is what the returned value:

```
{
  "response": {
    "players": [
      {
        "steamid": "76561198260508210",
        "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
        "profilestate": 1,
        "personaname": "xGrow ◔ ⌣ ◔",
        "lastlogoff": 1487378601,
        "commentpermission": 1,
        "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/xgrow/",
        "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9bc4b0e198dfcc919cbcc781beb5886acaa9daee.jpg",
        "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9bc4b0e198dfcc919cbcc781beb5886acaa9daee_medium.jpg",
        "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9bc4b0e198dfcc919cbcc781beb5886acaa9daee_full.jpg",
        "personastate": 1,
        "realname": "Pedro",
        "primaryclanid": "103582791434436747",
        "timecreated": 1447526746,
        "personastateflags": 0,
        "loccountrycode": "PT"
      }
     ]
   }
}
```

To create a player object, code as follows:

```
<?php $json = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=270EBE5B0B2501EE0FC750196325406B&steamids=76561198260508210");
 $decode = json_decode($json,1);

 $player = $decode['response']['players'][0];

 echo $player['realname'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because **realname** is not in the main part of the array. You should see it like this:

`json -> "response" -> "players"[0] -> "realname"`

So you would need to do something like this:

```
$realname = $decode->response->players[0]->realname;
```